# Perform segue after UIAlertController is dismissed

Tags: swift, segue, uialertcontroller

I've had similar problems in the past with `UIAlertController` in the sense that there's always a lag on the UI thread after the `UIAlertController` is dismissed.
My problem right now is that I want to perform a segue if the user clicks on the "Okay" `UIAlertAction` and nothing happens if "Cancel" `UIAlertAction` is pressed.
This is my code:

```
// create the uialertcontroller to display
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Do you need help?",
                              message: "Would you like to look for a consultant?",
                              preferredStyle: .alert)
// add buttons
let okay = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes, please.", style: .default, handler: {_ in
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil)
})
let no = UIAlertAction(title: "No, I'm okay.", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
alert.addAction(okay)
alert.addAction(no)
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

What is currently happening is when I tap "Okay" the segue is performing, but I can only see the last moments of the transition (i.e the animation starts while the `UIAlertController` is being dismissed).
How do I make the segue start once the `UIAlertController` is dismissed?

<s>Note - I prefer not solving this in a hacky method like performing the segue after a fixed delay if there's another way.</s>

Thanks!

Comment: @matt so there isn't really a way to do this unless I animate after `n` seconds? Also - no where did I say forbid

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is in this code:

```
let okay = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes, please.", style: .default, handler: {_ in
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil)
})
```

The `handler:` is not a *completion* handler. It runs *before* the alert is (automatically) dismissed. Thus, you are starting the segue while the alert is still present.

If you prefer not to use [`delay`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/341994) (though I see nothing wrong with that approach), what I would try is this:

```
let okay = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes, please.", style: .default, handler: {_ in
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil)
    })
})
```

Comment: I figured - is there any way to perform this after the controller is dismissed?

Comment: how did I tell you not to? If you're referring to my Note, it just means I of course prefer a method that doesn't have a static dispatch after time :)

Comment: fyour answer doesn't contain a dispatch after so I don't understand why wanting to learn a good solution is unfair?

Comment: To be fair I said a hacky method. And I would argue that performing something after a hard coded amount of time isn't good practice when there's a method that calls an action after*something* happens. Anyways thanks for the help

Comment: I don't see why one approach is more or less "hacky" than the other. Either way, you are working around a (strange) limitation of the API. Any time you have to do that, it's a hack (and a flaw in the API). But what that means is you should file a bug with Apple, not tell me what kind of answer to give.

Comment: This is an elegant solution. I prefer this to using a delay also.

Comment: @matt  I have used your code posted above, and my unwindsegue is not performed. I am sure it's called because if segue.identifier is wrong it will throw an error.